# saving views state before transition

Tags: android, transition

could u help me with such trouble.

I wanna to use Scenes and TransitionManager for showing beautiful transition effects like that:

```
final Scene scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.bottom), R.layout.scene_pause, MainActivity.this);

TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();
set.addTransition(new Fade().setDuration(1500));
set.addTransition(new ChangeBounds().setDuration(1700));
set.setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER);               
set.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
TransitionManager.go(scene,set);
```

It works, but as i understood, Scene takes Views state (e.g. drawables, backgrounds and so on) from corresponding layout (in my case R.layout.scene_pause). In this layout i have a 3-state button and current stay of this button after transition is always the same as it is in layout file, independently of previous state of this button. How can i save or set state of my views before starting transition?

Comment: Have a look to this articles, they provide a detailed information of how the transitions framework works http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html

Comment: thanks a lot for the link, but  as i understood they consider activity and fragment transitions, and i dont need that, i need simple transition between 2 scenes in one particular activity without any fragments, simply change between 2 views

Comment: Yeah, I provided this link as it explains how it works behind the scenes, doesn't matter if it is a fragment, an activity or a view. The transition framework is always working the same

Comment: solved this using constructor [public Scene (ViewGroup sceneRoot, ViewGroup layout)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Scene.html#Scene%28android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29)

Answer (score 0):

it may be achieved by such code:

```
ViewGroup bottom = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.bottom);
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.scene1_play,null);
final Scene scene1 = new Scene(bottom,layout);
```

After that we can find any view from the layout using layout.findViewById method, so we can change backgrounds, text, drawables and so on BEFORE trasition. after all changes will be done, we should start transition using

```
 TransitionManager.go(scene1);
```